# MySQL PDO inserting wrong values (CSV data source)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-into

I have a table like so.

```
CREATE TABLE `GBPAUD` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency_pair` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sell` float NOT NULL,
  `buy` float NOT NULL,
  `spread` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have written a script that opens CSV files, itterates the rows and inserts them into the table.

After the script has run and i look in the database the table appears like this.

[image]

The code that inserts the data looks like so.

```
private function insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $result_set = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ".str_replace('_', '', $this->instrument)." (currency_pair, date, sell, buy, spread) VALUES (:currency_pair, :date, :sell, :buy, :spread)"); 
    $result = $result_set->execute(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, 'spread' => (float)$spread)); 
}
```

I print out the values just before the exacute stament and the values are correct.

```
Array
(
    [:currency_pair] => GBP/AUD
    [:date] => 2007-11-01 14:06:04.000
    [:buy] => 2.273400
    [:sell] => 2.272500
    [spread] => 0
)
```

Anyone have any idea why its not inserting my data?

EDIT:
DB connection code

```
define("DSN", "mysql:dbname=rates_test;host=localhost;port=3306");
define("USER", "blah");
define("PASS", "blah");
$pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
```

**EDIT 2**

I have taken the insert out of the function and added to the while loop im doing so you can see whats happening.

```
while( false !== ( $data = fgetcsv($file) ) ) {
        if(array(null) !== $data){ //skip blank lines
            $currencyPair = $data[$column['columns']['instrument']];
            $date = $data[$column['columns']['date']];
            $sell = $data[$column['columns']['sell']];
            $buy = $data[$column['columns']['buy']];
            $spread = (float)$buy - (float)$sell;

            echo "value => " . $currencyPair . "\r\n";
            echo "value => " . $date . "\r\n";
            echo "value => " . $sell . "\r\n";
            echo "value => " . $buy . "\r\n";
            echo "value => " . $spread . "\r\n";

            echo var_dump(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, ':spread' => (float)$spread));                     

            $result_set = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ".str_replace('_', '', $this->instrument)." (currency_pair, date, sell, buy, spread) VALUES (:currency_pair, :date, :sell, :buy, :spread)");         
            $result = $result_set->execute(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, ':spread' => (float)$spread));    
        }   
}
```

and here is the result

```
value => GBP/AUD
value => 2007-10-28 21:21:48.000
value => 2.229000
value => 2.229900
value => 0

array(5) {
  [":currency_pair"]=> string(15) "GBP/AUD"
  [":date"]=> string(47) "2007-10-28 21:21:48.000"
  [":buy"]=> float(0)
  [":sell"]=> float(0)
  [":spread"]=> float(0)
}
```

**Edit 3:**

I solved it, but its a bit hacky. Also i have no control over over these CSV's so any invisible characters can be in it. Can anyone please confirm if this is enough to handle any invisible characters there may be? ( i have not put this into a function yet, but i am doing the same for ever variable im inserting)

```
    $buy = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $buy);
    $buy = (strpos($buy, ':') && strpos($buy, '-')) ? array_shift(explode('.', $buy)) : $buy;
```

I do not like what i am doing with the date, but i cannot think of any other ways (i cannot parse a legitamate date straight from the CSV because of the invisable characters) even without the invisible characters removed i cannot parse a date because some feilds have more than 6 micro seconds (PHP can only handel 6)

Comment: May be because `'spread' => (float)$spread)`. You missed `:`. Change it to like `':spread' => (float)$spread)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i'm surprised PDO didn't complain about it, but unfortunately this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Thats because its not actually necessary

Comment: You are changing table name by replacing `_`. So, is table name correct? Have you checked it?

Comment: `private function insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $result_set = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO GBPAUD (currency_pair, date, sell, buy, spread) VALUES (:currency_pair, :date, :sell, :buy, :spread)"); 
    $result = $result_set->execute(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, ':spread' => (float)$spread)); 
}`

Comment: Are you sure that table is empty before you start and you are not looking at old data at the top of the table? Silly question I know, but I have done it!

Comment: Thanks for the info @RiggsFolly did not realise it was not necessary.

Comment: Good practice to keep them though, makes it obvious whats going on

Comment: yup i have checked @RiggsFolly i truncate the table before i run the script every time.

Comment: @Anant And what is your point. Slabs of code in comments are totally UNREADABLE!

Comment: Yes @Nana it is inserting into the correct table. the database has just that 1 table in. (also i printed out and it is correct)

Comment: @Anant and if you posted all that just to say put a colon in front of `spread` like this `':spread'` We already covered that

Comment: ___Side Point___ floats's will bite you in the ahhhs eventually. You would be better with `decimal()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  you forgot to see `INSERT INTO GBPAUD`

Comment: @Anant Like I said UNREADABLE

Comment: @Anant And as the query seems to be creating data in the correct table that probably is not the problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are correct it is not the problem. Hardcoding GBPAUD will not have any effect

Comment: I have added the connection code for you. I think i have found out some new information that might help us solve this. Give me 15 minutes and ill update the question.

Comment: @Simplify your code by organizing it a class. Casting values to floats in the middle of trying to execute the query....simplify. Efficiency does you no good if does not work in the real world. I understand what you are doing, but you can do this better.

Comment: I have changed abit of my code so that you can see what is happening clearer. please check out EDIT 2

Comment: You can see that the bits for the strings are more than the strings actully are , so must still be hidden cahracters. Anyone have some good regex that can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrapped a bit of code around your posted code and it works fine. I did not even change the code for the `spread` to `:spread` suggestion.

I did however add a try/catch block as I see you set the mode to throw Exceptions, but the catch block was never activated.

```
<?php

class tst
{
    private $pdo;
    private $instrument = 'gbp_aud';

    public function __construct()
    {
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        /*** mysql username ***/
        $username = 'test';
        /*** mysql password ***/
        $password = 'test';
        /*** database name ***/
        $dbname = 'test';

        try {

            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND,'SET NAMES UTF8');

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    }

    private function insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
            $result_set = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ".str_replace('_', '', $this->instrument)." (currency_pair, date, sell, buy, spread) VALUES (:currency_pair, :date, :sell, :buy, :spread)");
            $result = $result_set->execute(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, 'spread' => (float)$spread));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo());
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function doit($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
        $this->insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread);
    }
}

$test = new tst();

$currencyPair   = 'GBP/AUD';
$date           = '2007-11-01 14:06:04.000';
$buy            = 2.273400;
$sell           = 2.272500;
$spread         = 0;
$test->doit($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread);

$currencyPair   = 'GBP/AUD';
$date           = '2007-11-02 13:06:04.000';
$buy            = 2.276600;
$sell           = 2.278800;
$spread         = 0.4;
$test->doit($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread);
```

Results:

[image]

I just read your last question, and I have to assume that you still have some odd characters in your data feed to this process.

Do a `var_dump()` of the array that you feed to the `->execute()` statement, that will likely show more than a simple `print_r()`

### UPDATE

The issue is that the older files are encoded in UNICODE and the new files are simple ASCII single byte encoded.

I converted the Older files offline so to speak back to ASCII and this code loaded an old and new file quite happily

The only remaining complication if that the older files dont have column names on row 1 and the field order is a little different, but thats just a FLOC. See the code below.

```
<?php

class tst
{
    private $pdo;
    private $instrument = 'gbp_aud';

    public function __construct()
    {
        /*** mysql hostname ***/
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        /*** mysql username ***/
        $username = 'test';
        /*** mysql password ***/
        $password = 'test';
        /*** database name ***/
        $dbname = 'test';

        try {

            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND,'SET NAMES UTF8');

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    }

    private function insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
            $result_set = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ".str_replace('_', '', $this->instrument)." (currency_pair, date, sell, buy, spread) VALUES (:currency_pair, :date, :sell, :buy, :spread)");
            $result = $result_set->execute(array(':currency_pair' => $currencyPair, ':date' => $date, ':buy' => (float)$buy, ':sell' => (float)$sell, 'spread' => (float)$spread));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            print_r($this->pdo->errorInfo());
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function doit($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread){
        $this->insert($currencyPair, $date, $buy, $sell, $spread);
    }
}

$test = new tst();

// One old and one new format file
$files = array('GBP_AUD_Week1.csv', 'GBP_AUD_Week5.csv');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $old_format = true;
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // test old or new file layout
            if ( $data[0] == 'lTid' ) {
                // New file layout
                $old_format = false;
                // Skip the title row
                 continue;
            }
            if ( $old_format ) {
                $test->doit($data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[4]-$data[3]);
            } else {
                $test->doit($data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[5], $data[5]-$data[4]);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably right, its is probably to do with odd characters, seen as your code works. do you think addcslashes() will be enough to show all of the invisable characters

Comment: Ah right ok, this is the main issue im having, I have no control over the CSV. This script is scraping mass amount of data from a website. http://ratedata.gaincapital.com the data on this website is very inconsistant. I need to figure out a way to strip literally everything other than the visible data as i never know what the input will be.

Comment: sure here is a link to google drive. I can not thank you enough for this help. what i am doing is very time sensative and iv been stuck all day. <3

Comment: I have solved the issue with some regex (its very hacky though) i have added another edit. Can you please take a look

Comment: Thats so strange, so do you think my regex will be enough to resolve this issue? also do you have a better way i can handel this date? (more info in edit 3)

Comment: you are correct they are not, i have built a function that can dynamically select the column that it needs. reguardless of where it is in the CSV

Comment: yes this is very confusing, for some reason the only way i can get PHP to recognise the strings from the CSV is by using that bit of regex. Thank you so much for the help your a life saver. Id like to give you some rep for the help but the solution to this question is in this comment section. On stack over flow is it ok to accept an answer if the awnser is in the comments (im a stack overflow neewbie and they are threatening to stop me asking questions because apparently mine arn't well received)

Comment: Sorry only jsut saw this, yes i calulate from buy - sell

Comment: I think I have spotted your problem with those files, few mins while I make sure.

Comment: You are an absolute legend

Comment: Id like to be able to do it inside the PHP code, i have about 25 currency pairs (like GBPAUD) each with about 250 csv's :P Are you happy to help me with that? If not do not worry, you have done enough. ill figure out how to do myself. thanks again.....so much.

Comment: Got to go to a meeting now, So I will leave that to you. I think `iconv()` will help you with that.

Comment: Oh and you can remove the (cast) now as well, I assume you only added that to attempt to solve what you thought was the problem

Comment: Thank you so much. Absolute life saver. yea you are correct. i thought maybe the issue was a datatype one.